# how to let firefox add-on's observer get the id/name of a http post request?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I can use the addObserver() function to add an observer of "http-on-modify-request" and get the observer funtion started when firefox observes an post request.
Then i can use the the variables or methods of httpchannel to get the cookies/originalURI/referrer of the post request. But how can I get the id/name of the form which issues the post request?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm pretty sure http requests don't have an id/name. Others would have to verify though. Name of form? Thats different than the id im pretty sure. Interesting q though.

Comment: Exactly, I mean the id/name of the form. You can use getElementById() to get a element.

Comment: Ok this is what I'm thinking to get the form. Using `http-on-open-request` get the current window, and then uses focus manager `Services.fm` to get the currently selected item and then use dom `.parentNode` to go up till you find `form` (if reach `body` element then no form) what do you think?

Comment: Thanks, but it may not works when a request is sent from a un-active form.

Comment: why do you need this information?

Comment: I want to add a http-header param into each post. The value of the param is based on the name of the <form>.